# CSS to align child elements vertically without changing horizontal position within a timeline

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, timeline

I'm Typically a python dev so I haven't had much interaction with CSS so go easy on me..

That being said here we go:

I'm working with a timeline library 'react-timelines' and need to add some functionality for displaying items that occur within overlapping time periods. This is not currently supported by the library and I'm looking for hopefully a simple fix within the style sheet to allow to fix how the child objects are displayed.

Current behavior is that items in timeline overlap, but I need to be able to see all items in timeline. This would require them to stack dynamically within their row on the timeline if the items occur within the same block of time.

Current Behavior: [currently observed behavior, line items overlapping eachother](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPSkt.png)

Desired Behavior: [Desired Behavior, line items dynamically stacking vertically to allow for multiple items in the row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ebBbA.png)

I have tried adjusting the position attribute within the child elements from absolute to relative but that did not seem to make any difference on how they are positioned.

Current CSS block for parent and child elements are:

```
  .parent{
    position: relative;
    height: 61px;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
  }

  .child {
    position: absolute;
    height: 40px;
    top: 10px;
  }
```

Comment: You'll need to post the (relevant) "*[mcve]*" HTML along with enough of your CSS to reproduce your problem, or a simplified and representative version of your problem. I realise you're working with React, but please post the HTML that your browser puts together from the components, and not the jsx component.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

try use left property with position in you child element ;)

```
div {
    position: absolute;
    left: 190px;
    width: 200px;
    height: 120px;
    border: 3px solid green;
}
```

Here some references on  [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.php?filename=trycss_position_left)